# PostgreSQL Regex match for long file name pattern with extension and no path

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to use regex to match a long file name with a csv extension.

Sample file names:

```
    Always TheSameText_ExtractStoreLevelUnLtdByWeek_STORENAME_20160306.csv
    Always TheSameText_ExtractStoreLevelUnLtdByWeek_ANOTHERSTORENAME_20150705.csv
```

I am using:

```
    file_name_regex text := E'^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.csv$';
```

With a check :

```
    IF
            file_name !~ file_name_regex
    THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid data file name (% doesn''t match %)', file_name, file_name_regex;
    END IF;
```

I get:

```
    Invalid data file name (Always TheSameText_ExtractStoreLevelUnLtdByWeek_STORENAME_20150705.csv doesn't match ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.csv$)
```

I have googled, read and reread, but can't get my head around this.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: There is a space in the file name, so add it to the regex: `file_name_regex text := E'^[ a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.csv$';`

Comment: Holy Smokes! I can't believe I stared at this and missed a simple space. Thanks a million and such a quick response.Working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in the file name, so add it to the regex:

```
file_name_regex text := E'^[ a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.csv$';
                            ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY7aS5/1)